# Restore Purchases function - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

In my app, the user can make two different purchases.

Here's my paymentQueue function :

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .Purchased, . Restored:
                print("Product Purchased / Restored")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                // TO DO
                if selectedProduct == "product1" {
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "product1Purchased")
                } else if selectedProduct == "product2" {
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "product2Purchased")
                }
            case .Failed:
                print("Purchased Failed")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I created a variable named `selectedProduct` to detect which product the user select. If he click on the button to buy the first product, the variable `selectedProduct` hold the value "product1".

The problem is when the user click the Restore Purchases button, the app check if the selected product is "product1" or "product2", but `selectedProduct` has no value if the user click on the Restore Purchases button, so nothing happen.

How can I do please?

Comment: You should not be using `selectedProduct` to see what was purchased or restored. Look inside the transaction to know what was purchased or selected.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! What do you mean by "transaction" ?

Comment: Your `transaction` variable (actually your `trans` variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a variable such as `selectedProduct` to determine which product was purchased or restored. Look inside the `SKPaymentTransaction` for the needed information.

```
        case .Purchased, . Restored:
            print("Product Purchased / Restored")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

            if trans.payment.productIdentifier == "product1" {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "product1Purchased")
            } else if trans.payment.productIdentifier == "product2" {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "product2Purchased")
            }
```

Adjust as needed for your actual product ids.